# Dot matrix fast printing

Tags: java, printing, awt, epson, dot-matrix

I'd like to know, what practical way of printing on EPSON Dot Matrix printers in Java. I'm having the LX300+II model to play, with USB connectivity.

I searched too much on internet but all the codes available for network and serial(port LPT) printers.
like : https://code.google.com/p/escprinter/, http://devpath.blogspot.in/2008/01/java-como-imprimir-na-epson-lx-300-via.html

I tried with Java print service 2D Graphics, it works but taking time.

I know we have two ways of using this printer:

1. By directly raw ASCII data to printer
2. By Graphical printing, with graphical fonts and precise positioning.

How can I use both fast printing fonts (provided by 1) and precise positioning (provided by 2)? Any code or API?

Comment: Look at the manual for the printer to see if this is possible (no point searching for code if the printer can't do it).

Comment: Problem is solved, Just shared my USB printer and then it available on network path like "\\localhost\<printerName>".
But Now I am facing the other issue :(.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852321/esc-p-set-absolute-horizontal-print-position

Any body have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a third-party API, [RTextPrinter](http://java4less.com/textprinter/index.html) which seems to support the following Dot Matrix printer command sets:

- Epson ESCP and ESCP2 or compatible
- HP-PCL5 or compatible
- HP-PCL 3 (known also as Laset Jet Plus Emulation)
- IBM Proprinter or compatible
- IBM PPDS
- Diablo
- Plain (no features)

It supports the following features as listed in its details page:

- Font selection (courier ...)
- Font style (bold, italic and underlined)
- Font size (characters per inch)
- Lines (vertical and horizontal) and rectangles
- Character set managing and charater value mapping
- Other: subscripts and superscripts, double wide, landscape format and interline spacing

However, this is not a free API and you will have to purchase a license to use it. You can try a demo to see if it satisfies your requirement though.

Hope this helps.